# How can I Extract XML embedded in a JSON file in java

Tags: java, json, xml

I have a JSON file which contains the XML as its Value. How can I extract the XML from the JSON. Below are the sample input file and expected output

Sample input file:

```
{"RawXml":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>\r\n <VV>P0.64</VV>"}
```

here, I need the XML like the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<VV>PT0.64S</VV>
```

I used the below code to get the file from stream,

```
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject jsonObject;
                    jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

                    String xml = XML.toString(jsonObject);
```

However, I am getting something like (I am pasting a Partial Output),

```
"{&quot;RawXml&quot;:&quot;&lt;?xml version=\&quot;1.0\&quot; encoding=\&quot;UTF-8\&quot; standalone=\&quot;no\&quot;
```

Comment: Why aren't you just calling jsonObject.getString("RawXml"); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **org.apache.commons.lang** library

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 3.1, use

```
json-doc($inputFile)?RawXml => parse-xml()
```